How much tax do I pay if my deductions are more than my taxes owed?
To begin, I would like to say that I am 19 years old and this is my first time paying taxes for myself, so please inform me if I am not approaching this correctly. Be wary of a little bit of math.
I work as a baseball umpire (in the US) during the summer, and am considered an independent contractor (by way of signing a 1099). During the summer of 2023, I made $4240. With the 15.3% tax rate for independent contractors, this means I owe $648.72 in taxes.
The 2023 mileage deduction rate was 65.5 cents per mile. In one day, I would make a round trip of 86 miles (43 there and back), and I would make this trip twice a week, each Saturday and Sunday for 9 weeks total. So:
((Miles per day * days that I worked per week) * (weeks I worked)) * mileage deduction = total deduction
((86 * 2) * (9)) * .655 = $1013.94
This $1013.94 deduction is greater than the $648.72 taxed from my income. What does this mean I should do? Do I have to pay anything? Please let me know what the best course of action is. Thank y'all.
P.S: This is from mileage alone. I have a ledger of all of the equipment I had to purchase, and money spent on stuff like drinks and ice. Does this also count towards my deductions? Thanks again.

Unfortunately, mileage from home to work generally isn't deductible as it's considered commute costs.

@StanH That's only true to and from your regular place of work. If you have to travel for work then that's deductible.

crtobin34, is this your only income?

@DJClayworth, yes this is the entirety of the income I earned in 2023.

@StanH Don't umpires travel to different games all the time? Not very familiar with the role

@littleadv, it depends on where we are assigned for that specific weekend. I was only assigned to one location for the entirety of that summer.

then the comment is valid, you cannot deduct commute

@DJClayworth that's true, I was assuming it was just the one location.

I'm not American, but isn't this totally irrelevant? His total income is less than the standard deduction?

@crtobin34 you'll probably just owe SE tax and maybe state income tax. Like DJClaryworth said, you're under the standard deduction amount so even without deductions your taxable (federal) income might be $0.

@StanH, I live in Texas, which has no state income tax. Does this mean I should only pay the SE tax? Regarding mileage deduction, all of my coworkers are older than me and do it as a side-gig, but they all tell me that they have always written off their mileage + equipment. So I should pay SE tax based on my net income of (Income - expenses)? Sorry if I am making this difficult, as I am still trying to learn this whole tax thing...

@crtobin34 you'll need to file a federal tax return (Form 1040) to determine your tax liability. Being self-employed, you'll report your income/expenses on Schedule C. Just do your best - as long as you make a good-faith effort and don't do anything blatantly in disregard of the tax code, your most likely worst-case outcome is getting a letter in the mail saying the IRS thinks you owe a little bit more.


I ... am considered an independent contractor (by way of signing a 1099)

Some nits about terminology:
You're classified as an independent contractor or an employee based on what and how you do, not what and how you sign. You can read more about it at the IRS page on the topic. On a State level, in California for example there are strict rules on who's an employee and who's a contractor. See the CA page about AB 5. Other States may have similar laws.
1099 is a form given to you at the end of the year (with a copy furnished to the IRS), that includes a full report of the payments you received from that payer throughout the year, and what the money was for. For example, banks give you 1099-INT for the interest they pay. Payment processors (like Paypal) give you 1099-K for the payments they processed for you. Contract employers will give you 1099-NEC. Nothing to sign there.

During the summer of 2023, I made $4240. With the 15.3% tax rate for independent contractors, this means I owe $648.72 in taxes.

That's not how it works.
The tax rate you mentioned is the self-employment tax. See the instructions to the Schedule SE you'd be attaching to your tax return to calculate it. This is on top of the income tax.

This $1013.94 deduction is greater than the $648.72 taxed from my income

Your gross income is $4240. The $648 is the tax you calculated (wrongly).
The math is like this:
GI = $4240 (gross income)
NI = $4240-1014 (gross income minus expenses) = 3226.
SE Tax = SETR * NI (SE tax rate * net income) = $493.58.
Income Tax = ITR * (NI - (SE Tax/2)) = whatever that is

The actual numbers will be slightly different of course. Follow the instructions for Schedule C, Schedule SE, and the form 1040 itself.

This is from mileage alone. I have a ledger of all of the equipment I had to purchase, and money spent on stuff like drinks and ice. Does this also count towards my deductions? Thanks again.

If this was ordinary and necessary then yes. Whether it is in fact ordinary and necessary - you'll need to ask a professional tax adviser (EA/CPA/Attorney licensed in your State).

You might want to discuss your options for tax deferred retirement savings, if you don't need the money right now. Just investing the $4240 in a Roth IRA now can give you >$100K tax free at retirement without any additional investments ever.

I would not consult a professional tax advisor for a $4000 income, even in the US. The baseball leagure who hired you (or one of the other umpires) should be able to provide adequate advice. Also, he's 19. Let him have some fun before he starts putting all his earnings into retirement savings.

That's fair, but technically won't stand scrutiny in audit. CPA advice will. But for such a low amount the cost may not be worth the risk protection, you're right.

In my country the worst a 19 year old baseball umpire would get if they messed up their mileage deductions would be a polite letter telling them they had to pay a bit more tax. And they wouldn't expect you to even file for $4000 of income. But of course that's because I come from a country that doesn't have a batshit crazy tax system.

@DJClayworth in the US you must file if you have more than $600 of earned income. Yeah, I agree with you that the risk is low.
